# How to make python chatroom communicate across different PCs?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, python-multithreading

I have been trying to create a simple python chatroom, which uses a server and a client program. When I try to load both the server and client on one machine, it works fine, but it does not work on multiple machines. How do I go about this? Brand new to this, so excuse me if I sound completely stupid :/

Here is the code for the server program

```
#server.py
import socket
import threading
import random
port = random.randint(8000,8099)
my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
PORT = port
ADDRESS = "0.0.0.0"
broadcast_list = []
my_socket.bind((ADDRESS, PORT))
print("Server created: PYCOM-PRERELEASE_MS1@"+ str(PORT) +": \nAddress: " + str(ADDRESS) + '\nPort Generated: ' + str(PORT))
print('PYCOM V0.01: THIS IS PRE-RELEASE SOFTWARE, WHICH MAY CONTAIN BUGS.')
def accept_loop():
    while True:
        my_socket.listen()
        client, client_address = my_socket.accept()
        broadcast_list.append(client)
        start_listenning_thread(client)
        
def start_listenning_thread(client):
    client_thread = threading.Thread(
            target=listen_thread,
            args=(client,) #the list of argument for the function
        )
    client_thread.start()
    
def listen_thread(client):
    while True:
        message = client.recv(1024).decode()
        if message:
            print(f"{message}")
            broadcast(message)
        else:
            print(f"client has been disconnected : {client}")
            return


        
def broadcast(message):
    for client in broadcast_list:
        try:
            client.send(message.encode())
        except:
            broadcast_list.remove(client)
            print("a user has disconnected")
accept_loop()
```

and the code for the client program:

```
#client.py

import socket

import threading

nickname = input("Choose your nickname : ").strip()

while not nickname:

    nickname = input("Your nickname should not be empty : ").strip()

nickstr = str(nickname)

my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = "localhost" # "127.0.1.1"

my_socket.connect((host, int(input('Enter Port:'))))

my_socket.send(("A new user connected as '" + nickstr + "'").encode())

print("Connected to PyCom, Type a message, updates should be live. \n")

def thread_sending():

    while True:

        message_to_send = input()

        if message_to_send:

            message_with_nickname = nickname + " : " + message_to_send

            my_socket.send(message_with_nickname.encode())

def thread_receiving():

    while True:

        message = my_socket.recv(1024).decode()

        print(message)

thread_send = threading.Thread(target=thread_sending)

thread_receive = threading.Thread(target=thread_receiving)

thread_send.start()

thread_receive.start
()
```

What should I do to edit this if I want to communicate across multiple machines on the same LAN?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is local for that computer only. "What should I do to edit this if I want to communicate across multiple machines on the same LAN?" You use the private IP address of the server.